# Syntax highlighting for Kendo UI templates

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-template

Does there exist a program capable of syntax highlighting Kendo UI templates. They are very difficult to read in visual studio. Even if there is not plugin, is there an editor?
Does their syntax perhaps match another template format?

Examples of the syntax can be seen [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/templates/overview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try setting the type attribute of the script tag to "text/html". Some people find it easier to read.

Comment: Telerik confirmed that this is fine, you just have to set the type tag to something as long as it's not text/javascript
http://www.telerik.com/forums/can-you-confirm-that-x-kendo-template-is-not-required-